# How to disable global minor mode in individual buffer for emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

I have enable smart-tab mode as global minor mode by

```
(global-smart-tab-mode 1)
```

and want to disable it in eshell-mode,

```
(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (smart-tab-mode -1)))
```

but It seems not work and I'm sure this hook have been executed.
If I manually run `(smart-tab-mode -1)` in eshell, It is OK.

I don't know why, could someone help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: Duplicate of [automatically disable a global minor mode for a specific major mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837511/automatically-disable-a-global-minor-mode-for-a-specific-major-mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the deactivation of the minor mode in `eshell-mode-hook` and the activation caused by `global-smart-tab-mode` are called in the wrong order.

Recent versions of smart-tab.el have a `smart-tab-disabled-major-modes` variable to which you could add `eshell-mode`, i.e. `(add-to-list 'smart-tab-disabled-major-modes 'eshell-mode)`.

Answer (score 0):

There are different versions of smart-tab.el around - which one do you use? If it's [John Anderson's version](https://github.com/genehack/smart-tab), you don't need to add a hook, you can simply customize the variable  `smart-tab-disabled-major-modes` by invoking

```
M-x customize-variable <ENTER> smart-tab-disabled-major-modes <ENTER>
```

and then adding "eshell-mode" to the list.

If you are using [Daniel Hackney's version](https://github.com/haxney/smart-tab) there is a new function `turn-off-smart-tab-mode` which you can use instead of `(smart-tab-mode -1)` in your above code.