# Emacs: How to disable specific global mode in major-mode hook?

Tags: emacs, major-mode

I use `global-autopair-mode`, but with Ruby the `ruby-electric-mode` provides better autopairing.

I'm a n00b to Emacs and Lisp, so I would have thought you could do something like:

```
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
             (autopair-mode nil)
             (ruby-electric-mode t))
```

This however doesn't work. Is there a way to disable global modes within a major-mode hook?

Currently I'm using the last solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837511/automatically-disable-a-global-minor-mode-for-a-specific-major-mode), but it's not very neat and clean.

Comment: Duplicate of [automatically disable a global minor mode for a specific major mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837511/automatically-disable-a-global-minor-mode-for-a-specific-major-mode)

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/34660219/2402577

Answer (score 5):

autopair mode honors `autopair-dont-activate`, used like so:

```
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
             (setq autopair-dont-activate t)
             (ruby-electric-mode t))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `(autopair-mode nil)` with `(autopair-mode -1)`.