# How to turn off company mode in org mode?

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode, spacemacs

I'm using spacemacs and tried to turn off company mode in org mode while keeping it in other major modes. I've tried the following:

```
(global-company-mode '(not org-mode))
```

but it's not working.

Comment: You should post on http://emacs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At the Spacemacs configuration layer level you can disable auto-completion layer for a set of layers with the following line in `dotspacemacs-configuration-layers` (for instance disabling auto-completion for both org and git)

```
(auto-completion :disabled-for org git)
```

Comment: This is broken now per [issue](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/14835). And none of methods work right now, I can only disable auto-completion layer completely.

Answer (score 19):

Disable from `org-mode-hook` (this method will work with pretty much any globalized minor mode and major mode):

```
(defun jpk/org-mode-hook ()
  (company-mode -1))
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook #'jpk/org-mode-hook)
```

Or use company's configuration variable:

```
(setq company-global-modes '(not org-mode))
```

Comment: In order to turn off multiple modes can I just `(another-mode -1)` below of the `(company-mode -1)`?

Comment: @alper Yes, you can run whatever code you want in your hook function.