# how to disable hl-line feature in specified mode

Tags: emacs, elisp

i enable hl-mode in global scope with the following code.

```
(global-hl-line-mode t)
```

to turn off hl-line feature in a specified mode. i do it with the following code.

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook (lambda () (global-hl-line-mode 0)))
```

but it turns off the hl-line feature for global scope.

how to disable hl-line feature in a specified mode?

Comment: possible duplicate of [automatically disable a global minor mode for a specific major mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837511/automatically-disable-a-global-minor-mode-for-a-specific-major-mode)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is often information and documentation in the `Commentary`
section in the source file.

```
[...]
;; You could make variable `global-hl-line-mode' buffer-local and set
;; it to nil to avoid highlighting specific buffers, when the global
;; mode is used.
[...]
```

Thus, you can put something like this in your `.emacs`.

```
(global-hl-line-mode)
(make-variable-buffer-local 'global-hl-line-mode)
(add-hook 'some-mode-hook (lambda () (setq global-hl-line-mode nil)))
...
```

Comment: This is not working for me. I tried the following: `(add-hook 'term-mode-hook (lambda () (setq global-hl-line-mode nil)))`. I am trying to  turn off the `hi-line` feature when I am in `ansi-term` mode. Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps `setq-local` instead of `make-variable-buffer-local`?

Answer (score 1):

use `hl-line-mode` insted of `global-hl-line-mode`.

EDIT: You're right.  This doesn't work.

The commentary says that the global-mode isn't meant to be used.  I take it to
mean that you can't selectively disable it once enabled.

I enable the `hl-line-mode` in major-mode hooks where I need it.

Comment: i already try that way. but "(hl-line-mode 0)" can not turn off hl-line that turn on by "(global-hl-line-mode t)"

Answer (score 0):

write the following line in your dotEmacs file, and use f5 to toggle the hl-line-mode

`(global-set-key [f5] 'hl-line-mode)`