# major-mode hook configuration affects other buffers

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, xemacs, major-mode

Let me start by saying I'm very new to emacs.

I'm attempting to create customizations for major-modes.  While my settings are functioning correctly, I'm observing that when I open a new buffer, that buffers major-mode customization is being applied to other buffers of a different type.

For instance, if I open a file named 'Makefile', makefile-mode is used and my customizations are applied.  If I then open another file such as 'test.c', c-mode is used but customizations from makefile-mode are merged with customizations from c-mode.

The relevant portions of my .emacs file can be seen below:

```
(defun c-mode-settings ()
    (c-set-style                   "bsd")
    (set-buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
    (show-paren-mode               1)

    (setq c-basic-offset        4)
    (setq tab-width             4)
    (setq indent-tabs-mode      nil)
    (setq c-tab-always-indent   t)
    (setq require-final-newline t)
)

(defun makefile-mode-settings ()
    (setq whitespace-style '(tabs spaces space-mark tab-mark face lines-tail))
    (whitespace-mode       t)
    (show-paren-mode       1)

    (setq tab-width             4)
    (setq require-final-newline t)
)

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook        'c-mode-settings)
(add-hook 'makefile-mode-hook 'makefile-mode-settings)
```

How can I keep these mode hooks from affecting other buffers in different modes?

Thanks!
Andrew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to take into account, that some variables are becoming local to buffer when set, while some are global.  Usually they have corresponding comment in their description (use `C-h v var-name` to get this description.

In some cases, you can force that any variable become local to buffer, using the

```
(set (make-local-variable 'var-name) var-value)
```

but you need to be careful with this.

Comment: Looking at the description helps.  Is there a way to force a global-minor-mode to become local?  Specifically the show-paren-mode, as this is what's causing problems.

Comment: user1902144: See [automatically disable a global minor mode for a specific major mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837511/automatically-disable-a-global-minor-mode-for-a-specific-major-mode/6839968)