# How can I speed up Emacs DocView mode?

Tags: emacs, docview

I'm using a fairly standard install:

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (installed less than a week ago)
- GNU Emacs 24.1

And when I open a PDF file in Emacs, it's terribly slow. There's a 2-3 second delay when simply scrolling with the mouse, 1-2 second delay when using `n`, `p`, `C-p`, `C-n`, etc.

This is with a 20-page doc. With a 50-page doc like [this one](http://www.symantec.com/content/en/us/enterprise/media/security_response/whitepapers/w32_stuxnet_dossier.pdf), Emacs becomes unusable (constant freezing), so the problem gets worse with document size.

**How would I go about fixing this?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When I ran `emacs -Q`, the problem went a way. I isolated it to this line in my `.emacs.d/init.el` file:

```
(global-linum-mode 1)
```

If I comment that out and restart Emacs, I can scroll on PDFs and I get no UI delay whatsoever. If I turn it back on with `M-x global-linum-mode`, the long lag between mouse scroll and UI update comes back.

Comment: This might prove useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837511/automatically-disable-a-global-minor-mode-for-a-specific-major-mode

Comment: Yes, that was my next question :) I'll try out the suggestions asap. ty

Answer (score 7):

To disable linum-mode when you are in DocView mode, you can use the following setup file:
[setup-linum.el](https://github.com/Khady/emacs.d/blob/master/setup-linum.el)
You can customize by editing line number 5