# Disabling a package in emacs term-mode

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

I have a package (evil) that isn't playing nice with ansi-term. I am trying to have emacs disable evil-mode when term-mode is active. I am using the following command to try to do so

```
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook (lambda() (evil-mode -1)) )
```

However, this somehow disables evil mode in every mode except for term-mode once I open ansi-term. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps consider `C-z`, apparently this guy http://blog.binchen.org/?p=651 actually uses evil to solve a problem (unless I'm mistaken)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't reproduce this on my setup (Emacs 24.3, latest Evil from MELPA). Try this:

```
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook 'evil-emacs-state)
```

or

```
(add-hook 'term-mode-hook 'evil-insert-state)
```

This works for me. (I usually use insert state because I can jump right into normal state quickly).

Comment: This (with `evil-emacs-state`) sounds like a working way of doing what I had thought my answer would do.

Answer (score 5):

A quick look at the code shows that `evil-mode` is a global minor mode, so it affects all buffers.

The functions `turn-on-evil-mode` and `turn-off-evil-mode` are provided to enable or disable evil for the current buffer only (these functions enable or disable `evil-local-mode`, which is the per-buffer mode), however global minor modes enable themselves *after* mode hooks have run (see [automatically disable a global minor mode for a specific major mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837511/automatically-disable-a-global-minor-mode-for-a-specific-major-mode/6839968#6839968)) so it's best to see whether the global mode has some built-in support for disabling itself in specified circumstances.

In the case of evil-mode, it looks like the various "state" options facilitate this, with 'Emacs state' (`"emacs"`) disabling all the Evil key-bindings, and `(evil-set-initial-state MODE STATE)` letting you configure the default state for a specified major mode.

So unless the incompatibility runs deeper than keybindings, I imagine that the following will do the trick, after loading the Evil library:

```
(evil-set-initial-state 'term-mode "emacs")
```

Comment: This gave me the error "Attempt to set a constant symbol: nil". I tried placing it in different parts of my .emacs file, but to no avail

Comment: I guess I must have misinterpreted something. I've added the evil-mode tag to the question; hopefully someone more knowledgeable will clarify. I'm not using Evil myself, so I'm not in a position to test any of this. You should be able to use the advice approach in the linked Q&A (with evil-local-mode), or append a custom after-change-major-mode hook, but it did look like there should be a nicer way.

Comment: `(evil-set-initial-state 'term-mode 'emacs)` works for me

Answer (score 4):

I was surprised to reproduce this potential bug.

A solution is to use `C-z` in the term buffer; it will just break out of evil mode.

Answer (score 0):

For vterm, this is what works for me:

```
(add-hook 'vterm-mode-hook 'evil-emacs-state)
```