# Disabling 'linum-mode' for speedbar when global 'linum-mode' is active

Tags: emacs, emacs-speedbar

I have `linum-mode` enabled globally in my Emacs configuration. Being enabled globally means it is also applied to the *speedbar* which is undesirable.

The only suggestion I found for this issue, was in the archived Emacs help mailing list, which suggests the following `speedbar-mode-hook`:

```
(add-hook 'speedbar-mode-hook (lambda () (linum-mode -1)))
```

Unfortunately adding this to my configuration doesn't have the desired effect and the speedbar still has line numbers.

**Edit:** the above `add-hook` seems to work correctly after all, at least for Emacs >= 24.3. Leaving question for reference purposes since there isn't any other relating to this matter on StackOverflow.

Comment: Your add-hook should have the intended effect if you use Emacs-24.4 (maybe even already 24.3, can't remember exactly when I made that change).

Comment: I must have changed the place in my `.emacs` where I put the `add-hook`, because now it is indeed working with Emacs-24.3. Thanks for the confirmantion @Stefan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `speedbar-before-popup-hook` hook for achieving what you want:

```
(add-hook 'speedbar-before-popup-hook (lambda () (linum-mode -1)))
```

I am not sure why the generic mode hook is not working, though.

Comment: The reason the mode hook doesn't work is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837511/automatically-disable-a-global-minor-mode-for-a-specific-major-mode/6839968#6839968

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  Since speedbar define the hook, I would say that speedbar code is misleading not to say buggy.

Comment: I am accepting this as a possible alternative for Emacs < 24.3, since with 24.3, `speedbar-mode-hook` seems to be working correctly after all.