# how to turn company-mode off in mini-buffer in specific major-mode

Tags: emacs, elisp

I turned company-mode globally. But I don't want it to be turned on for vhdl-mode.

I add hook to turn it off to vhdl-mode-hook. But it still working in the mini-buffer when in vhdl-mode.

How could I turn it off for the mini-buffer only when major-mode is vhdl-mode?

Comment: @phils thank you so much. After read your post and check the company-mode I found the solution for it. (It make not work on other mode). It has Exception list for global-company-mode. My solution is (global-company-mode '(not vhdl-mode)). It works well for me.

Comment: I've re-opened the question, given that you found a solution which is quite specific to the mode you asked about. Please post it as an Answer and then accept it? I'll leave the link to the other Q&A here for reference: [automatically disable a global minor mode for a specific major mode](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6837511/324105).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After read @phils's post for another question and check the company-mode I found the solution for it.

The *global-company-mode* can accept exception list as an optional argument.

So my solution is:

```
(global-company-mode '(not vhdl-mode))
```

It will apply company-mode on all *major-mode* except *vhdl-mode* works well for me.