# How to disable global minor mode in a specified major mode

Tags: emacs, minor-mode

I use Prelude, I want enable hs-minor-mode in all prog-modes, except web-mode. I wrote

```
(add-hook 'prog-mode-hook #'hs-minor-mode)          
(make-variable-buffer-local 'hs-minor-mode)        
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook (lambda () (setq hs-minor-mode nil)))
```

in personal.el, but it doesn't work!

What should I do?

Comment: Duplicate of [automatically disable a global minor mode for a specific major mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837511/automatically-disable-a-global-minor-mode-for-a-specific-major-mode)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normally, to disable a minor mode, it is not enough to set the variable.  You must call the mode function.  So try something like:

```
(add-hook 'web-mode-hook (lambda () (hs-minor-mode -1)))
```

Comment: Another way is to make your `prog-mode-hook` conditional on the current mode.

Comment: Would you please give me an example? I don't how to make prog-mode-hook conditional.

Comment: Put a function on the hook that does something like `(unless (eq major-mode 'web-mode) (hs-mode)))`.