# Emacs function returns Symbol's value as variable is void:

Tags: variables, emacs

I am fairly new to Emacs but I know enough to be dangerous. I've built my .emacs file from scratch and now have it in an org file. I am now trying to take it to the next level and make my configuration more user friendly for myself.

I mostly use Emacs for writing. Books, blogs, screenwriting, etc. I am trying to create a function that will turn on multiple modes and add the settings on the fly.

For example, I use olivetti-mode when writing. It centers the text. Each time I have to adjust the olivetti-set-width. I thought I would get fancy and enable the spell checker and turn off linum-mode as well.

However, every time I try it I get the error:

```
Symbol's value as variable is void: my-writing
```

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong? I've google-fu'd quite a bit but I clearly have a gap in my understanding of what I am doing.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(defun my-writing ()
"Start olivetti mode, set the width to 120, turn on spell-check."
((interactive)
 (olivetti-mode)
 (setq olivetti-set-width . 120)
 (flyspell-mode)
 (global-linum-mode 0)))

(add-hook 'olivetti-mode-hook 
    (lambda () olivetti-mode my-writing t))

#+END_SRC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable `global-linum-mode` for specific major-modes, see [automatically disable a global minor mode for a specific major mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837511/automatically-disable-a-global-minor-mode-for-a-specific-major-mode/6839968#6839968)

[Inasmuch as `olivetti-mode` is a minor-mode that is enabled subsequent to whatever major-mode is already present in the buffer, the original poster may wish to turn off `linum-mode` *locally* in the current buffer by adding `(linum-mode -1)` to the tail end of the function `my-writing` (see below).  That idea, however, assumes that the original poster wanted to have `linum-mode` active in the current buffer just prior to calling `my-writing`.]

The function `my-writing` in the initial question contains an extra set of parenthesis that should be omitted, and the hook setting is not in proper form.

`olivetti-set-width` is a function that takes one argument, so you cannot use `setq` -- see function beginning at line 197:  https://github.com/rnkn/olivetti/blob/master/olivetti.el  `setq` is used when setting a variable, *not* a function.

Although `flyspell-mode` is generally buffer-local, it is a good idea to get in the habit of using an argument of `1` to turn on a minor-mode or a `-1` or `0` to turn it off.  When an argument is omitted, calling the minor-mode works as an on/off toggle.

Unless there are other items already attached to the `olivetti-mode-hook` that require prioritization or special reasons for using a hook with buffer-local settings, you do not need the optional arguments for `add-hook` -- i.e., APPEND and LOCAL.

There is no *apparent* reason to call `(olivetti-mode)` as part of the `olivetti-mode-hook` that gets called automatically at the tail end of initializing the minor-mode, so there is now a check to see whether that mode has already been enabled.  The `olivetti-mode-hook` is being included in this example to demonstrate how to format its usage.  However, the original poster should consider eliminating `(add-hook 'olivetti-mode-hook 'my-writing)` as it appears to serve no purpose if the user will be calling `M-x my-writing` instead of `M-x olivetti-mode`.  The hook would be useful in the latter circumstance -- i.e., when typing `M-x olivetti-mode` -- in which case, there is really no need to have `(unless olivetti-mode (olivetti-mode 1))` as part of `my-writing`.

```lisp
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(defun my-writing ()
"Start olivetti mode, set the width to 120, turn on spell-check."
(interactive)
  (unless olivetti-mode (olivetti-mode 1))
  (linum-mode -1) ;; see comments above
  (olivetti-set-width 120)
  (flyspell-mode 1))

;; original poster to consider eliminating this hook
(add-hook 'olivetti-mode-hook 'my-writing)

#+END_SRC
```

Comment: I made all the changes and it looks exactly like yours. Now I get a new error: Lisp nesting exceeds 'max-lisp-eval-depth'.

Comment: My apologies for assuming that `olivetti-mode` was a major-mode -- it is in fact a minor-mode.  I have updated the code -- please try again with the amended version.

Comment: It works! Thank you for the help and the explanation. (I had tried this a few weeks ago and so I had to go through my file and clean out all the nonsense. Now it works perfectly.)

Answer (score 2):

[lawlist's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37997573/1281433) describes how you can go about doing what you're actually trying to accomplish, but the particular error you're getting is because Emacs Lisp (like Common Lisp, but not Scheme) is a [Lisp-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp#The_function_namespace).  When you associate a symbol with a function using **defun**, it doesn't make the  *value* of that symbol (as a variable) that function, it makes the *function* value of that symbol the function.  You'll get the same error in a much simplified situation:

```
(defun foo ()
  42)

(list foo)
```

The symbol **foo** has no value here as a variable. To get something that you could later pass to **funcall** or **apply**, you need to either use the symbol **foo**, e.g.:

```
(funcall 'foo)
;=> 42
```

or the form **(function foo)**:

```
(funcall (function foo))
;=> 42
```

which can be abbreviated with the shorthand **#'**:

```
(funcall #'foo)
;=> 42
```

You're getting the error because of:

```
(add-hook 'olivetti-mode-hook 
    (lambda () olivetti-mode my-writing t))
```

which tries to use **my-writing** as a variable, but it has no variable value at that point.