# Permanently disable a global minor for a major mode in Emacs

Tags: emacs, minor-mode

Since `doc-view-mode` is very slow with the enabled `linum-mode`, I am trying to disable it for that mode. The same question has been answered almost 6 years ago:
[automatically disable a global minor mode for a specific major mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837511/automatically-disable-a-global-minor-mode-for-a-specific-major-mode)

Following the answer of [phils](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6839968/3166723), I have put the following in my [.emacs](https://github.com/TedKingdom/Emacs-Init-file) file:

```
(define-global-minor-mode my-global-linum-mode global-linum-mode
(lambda ()
  (when (not (memq major-mode
                   (list 'doc-view-mode 'shell-mode)))
    (global-linum-mode))))
(my-global-linum-mode 1)
(add-hook 'doc-view-mode-hook 'my-inhibit-global-linum-mode)
(defun my-inhibit-global-linum-mode ()
  "Counter-act `global-linum-mode'."
  (add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook
            (lambda () (linum-mode 0))
            :append :local))
```

The problem is that I cannot make it work **permanently**. When I start a new buffer, the line numbers reappear in the buffer of `doc-view-mode`. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your own globalized minor mode is invoking the *global* linum minor mode instead of the *buffer-local* linum minor mode!

You wanted to do this:

```el
(define-global-minor-mode my-global-linum-mode linum-mode
  (lambda ()
    (when (not (memq major-mode
                     (list 'doc-view-mode 'shell-mode)))
      (linum-mode 1))))
(my-global-linum-mode 1)
```

I would suggest actually using `derived-mode-p` for your `major-mode` test:

```el
(define-globalized-minor-mode my-global-linum-mode linum-mode
  (lambda ()
    (unless (or (minibufferp)
                (derived-mode-p 'doc-view-mode 'shell-mode))
      (linum-mode 1))))
```

n.b. `define-globalized-minor-mode` is the same thing as `define-global-minor-mode`, but I prefer the "globalized" naming as it's slightly more indicative of what it's for (i.e. to take a buffer-local minor mode, and create a new global minor mode which *controls* that buffer-local mode -- enabling it or disabling it in many buffers, en masse. A 'regular' global minor mode would not depend upon a buffer-local minor mode in this way, so the "globalized" terminology is helpful to differentiate this kind of mode from other global modes).

n.b. As you're using a custom globalized minor mode, you don't need any of the `my-inhibit-global-linum-mode` code. That was an entirely different approach, and you can remove it from your .emacs file.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you very much for your answer that spans almost 6 years!

Comment: One more thing: how to add minibuffer to the list of exceptions? I don't need line numbers there?